# Imprimir informacion en HTML usando JavaScript y un JSON de una API REST

Tags: javascript, html, json

**Hola, he estado intentando recoger informacion usando XMLHttpRequest, para coger un JSON de una API Rest, imprime en consola el JSON pero no logro sacar esa info por HTML en mi web, necesito un contador de descargas de un programa.**

**Ej:** Descargas: ***x***

Pero por alguna razon no puedo sacar la informacion en la web...
Uso Apache2/VSCode/Chrome/XAMPP, por si ayuda, aqui esta el codigo:

**JSON**

```
{
"id": "78993",
"title": "PermaDeathCore",
"tag": "Permadeath HardCore Mode",
"current_version": "PDC",
"author": {
"id": "973464",
"username": "vo1d_dev"
},
"premium": {
"price": "0.00",
"currency": ""
},
"stats": {
"downloads": "12",
"updates": "0",
"reviews": "0",
"rating": "0"
}
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function JSONRequest(){

    let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.spigotmc.org/simple/0.1/index.php?action=getResource&id=78993');
    request.send();
    request.onload = () => {
    let JSONFile = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let downloads = JSON.parse(JSONFile.stats.downloads);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = downloads;
    }
}

JSONRequest();
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="/src/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="JSONRequest()">
        <strong>Downloads: <span id="output"></span></strong>
    </body>
    <script src="/src/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Si haces un console.log(request.responseText); te imprime en consola el resultado de la api?? intento replicar tu código pero tengo problemas con las cabeceras

Comment: Si, si eliminas el document.getElementById.... te devuelve en consola los datos en JSON de la API:

`node script.js` // Imprime el JSON

Comment: Por cierto veo que en tu html agregas 2 veces la etiqueta script llamando al mismo js. En tu caso dejalo en el head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function JSONRequest(){

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    request.onload = function() {debugger;
       let todo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = todo.title;
    }
    request.send();
}

JSONRequest();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

El problema está en el uso de [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) que estas usando en `onload`. Este tipo de funciones fueron añadidas en la versión ES6 de JS.

Se caracterizan por no crear un scope(a las variables que tiene acceso mientras la función se ejecuta), y si se usan dentro de una clase su `scope` es la misma clase hacen referencia al `this`. Sino siempre es el objeto global. En el navegador es `window` y en node `global`.

En tu caso, al usar arrow function `() => {}` pierdes el scope y por lo tanto, no tienes acceso a la variable `request`. Y al ser una petición asíncrona el `onload` se ejecuta cuando llega la respuesta desde el servidor y cuando eso ocurre la función `JSONRequest` ya no existe en el call stack y por lo tanto ni las variables que se crearon.

Para arreglar el error usa una función normal. Esta permitirá crear y acceder a las variables del scope y al `this` que hace referencia al objeto `request`.

Comment: Sigue sin aparecer, si utilizo el .innerHTML fuera de la funcion o arriba del JSONRequest si que lo imprime, el problema esta cuando esta dentro del onload... al cargar la pagina con el .innerHTML dentro del function() no lo carga.

Comment: prueba ahora he actualizado la respuesta

Comment: El error estaba en la API, tube que cambiar el modo de cargarla para que me devolviera el json de otra forma, tambien tube que utilizar `JSON.stringify` ya que al printear en HTML devuelve `[Object object]`, muchisimas gracias igualmente gracias a ti lo pude sacar.